Не получается создать рабочий .exe файл через pyinstaller
Пытаюсь из скрипта на пайтон самого простого создать исполняемый файл для запуска его на другом компьютере.Использую pyinstaller в виртуальном окружении в котором находится скрипт, установил pyinstaller, выполнил команду для конвертации в исполняемый файл, но при попытке его запустить ни какой реакции ни на клавишу Enter, ни на двойное нажатие мыши , уже пробовал cx_Freeze , auto-py-to-exe такая же картина... Скрипт самый простой чисто для проверки работоспособности pyinstaller
print('hello  pyinstaller ')
input()


дубликат

import os
print('hello  pyinstaller')
os.system("pause")

Проблема в "подвешивании" результатов работы программы на экране. Лично пробовал собрать это. Собирается.
